# resize window in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have a  tooltip that might be appear in 2 position : top & bottom
i want do this with jquery resize. when user resize his browser in with less than 768px , my tooltip appear on the top position and  when greater than 768px appear on bottom position but resize() wont work!!

```
$(window).ready(function () {
if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".green-tooltip").tooltip({placement: 'bottom'});
    });
}
else if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".green-tooltip").tooltip({placement: 'top'});
    });
}
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var wi = $(window).width();
        if (wi >= 768) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".green-tooltip").tooltip({placement: 'bottom'});
            });
        }
        else if (wi <= 767) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".green-tooltip").tooltip({placement: 'top'});
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready, $(document).ready everywhere...

Comment: How do you know its the `resize` that has a problem? Do you have any errors on your page console?

Comment: @mido22 is right. Why do you use `$(document).ready` inside `$(window).resize`?

Comment: console do not has any error

Comment: I test $(document).ready() but do not work.

Comment: `window.onresize=function(){ /*here your code*/ }` is far away better than the jQuery version cause is faster and ecma interpret it as native code. For width use: `window.innerWidth`. And get rid off those `document ready` from the resize script

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work out for u mate.. :)

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
        $(".green-tooltip").tooltip({
            placement: 'bottom'
        });

    } else if ($(window).width() <= 767) {

        $(".green-tooltip").tooltip({
            placement: 'top'

        });
    }
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    var wi = $(window).width();
    if (wi >= 768) {

        $(".green-tooltip").tooltip({
            placement: 'bottom'
        });

    } else if (wi <= 767) {

        $(".green-tooltip").tooltip({
            placement: 'top'

        });
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p312e9e5/)

Comment: I have added a fiddle in the answer..check it out mate..It works fine

Comment: I try it before with alert but my code doesn't work with this tooltip.

Comment: Its the tooltip that causes the problem.Either u have not included the bootstrap js that is required for the tooltip to work in your project

Comment: my tooltip work but not Displaced when resized my window . and I included bootstrap.js

Comment: I really can't comment about it,until i get a clear idea about it mate